# Change title of geom_histogram's legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `geom_histogram` created with `ggplot` and I need to change the legend's title.

I find a lot of links about doing it with `opts` but it is deprecated now. The `theme` command allows to change esthetics, but not the title of the legend itself.

Which is the way of doing it?

Comment: `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(title="TITLE"))`

Comment: @beetroot why are you assuming it's the `fill` aesthetic?

Comment: But, if the OP wasn't able to figure it out, it seems reasonable to further elaborate what the call is doing, no? And, it can be done more succinctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided which aesthetic that's shown in the legend. I usually prefer setting the legend title manually in `scale_…` calls (when necessary), but you can use `labs` with the aesthetic title mapping. i.e.…

- `labs(color='title')` to change the title of a legend/guide that maps the `color` aesthetic
- `labs(fill='title')` to change the title of a legend/guide that maps the `fill` aesthetic
- `labs(size='title')` to change the title of a legend/guide that maps the `size` aesthetic

(etc for all the other ones `geom_histogram` supports)

Comment: Grand it works. Sorry I am still in the process of understanding `ggplot2` ways, I thought it was not relevant and I was expecting kind of `+ legend(title="")` or similar. But thanks to your examples I managed to see how. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In general:
- `scale_aes_continuous("Title")` if the variable mapped to the chosen aesthetic (color, shape, linetype, fill, etc.) is continuous,
- `scale_aes_discrete("Title")` if the variable is discrete, or 
- `scale_aes_manual("Title", values = c(...))` if you want to supply the values yourself.

See `?scale_color_continuous` for more options

Since you didn't post a minimal example, here's mine:

```
data <- data.frame(
  x = c(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000, mean = 6)),
  group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 1000)
)
qplot(x = x, fill = group, data = data) + 
  scale_fill_discrete("New Title")
```

[image: Histogram with fill aesthetic and new legend title]